# Codeception and how to use Data driven library specify

Tags: php, codeception

I am trying to run data driven tests using Codeception 2.1.6.

This is the code that I have present.

```
<?php
use Codeception\Specify;

$this->specify("should calculate square numbers", function ($number, $square) {
    $this->assertEquals($square, $number * $number);
}, ['examples' => [[2, 4], [3, 9]]]);
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.6
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in C:\dev\tests\acceptance\TutorialCest.php on line 5
```

I'm not sure how to get past this issue. Any advice?

Comment: Is this code inside class?

Comment: no its not. Does it need to be? first time using php

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be inside method of the class to be able to access $this.
Another reason for using class is that Codeception\Specify is a trait.

So you can't use classless Cept format, and have to chose between Test format used in https://github.com/Codeception/Specify examples and Cest format documented in http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Cept-Cest-and-Test-Formats

If you didn't know that $this must be used inside class, I recommend reading about PHP objects and classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php